# Access custom properties of a particle system

Tags: python, scripting, particles, custom-properties

I want to access the custom properties of a particle system. For regular objects this is done using object.data["property_name"]. However, this does not work for particle systems although custom properties can be set for them in the particle system tab of the gui.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add custom properties to [ParticleSystem](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html). It doesn't derive from [ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID).

However what you see in the particle properties panel, is the [particle system's settings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html#bpy.types.ParticleSystem.settings). [ParticleSettings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSettings.html).

Here's a snippet to verify it :

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mod = obj.modifiers["ParticleSystem"]
particle_system = mod.particle_system
particle_settings = particle_system.settings
print(particle_settings["prop"])
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for!